# How to overwrite environment variables in Vue-cli3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

Let us assume we have a Vue.js project build with Vue-cli3 , package.json:

`{
 "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  ...
}`

Also, we have a plan to push our project to a public repository on GitHub, so we need different environment variables for public repo and for the local development.
Vue-cli 3 gives us `modes`: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes

I have such a files:

- .env
- .env.development
- .env.production
- .env.local
- .env.development.local
- .env.production.local

Content of .env:

`NODE_ENV=production
VUE_APP_PATH=http://website.com/
VUE_APP_API_ROUTE=api/v1/`

Content of .env.development:

`NODE_ENV=development
VUE_APP_PATH=http://dev-website.com/`

Content of .env.development.local:

`NODE_ENV=development
VUE_APP_PATH=http://localhost:8080/`

When I do `npm run serve` I expect `process.env.VUE_APP_PATH` will be equals `http://localhost:8080/` but unfortunately it stills = `http://dev-website.com/`.
So, the problem is variables from local env files (i.e. .env.development.local) are not overwrite existed from another env file (i.e. .env.development).

How can I use this vue-cli approach to overwrite neccessary variables? The documentation tells about priority: `An env file for a specific mode (e.g. .env.production) will take higher priority than a generic one (e.g. .env).` but with .local files it doesn`t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the `--mode` option within the npm script. So, in your instance you might want the `serve` script to look like:

`vue-cli-service serve --mode development.local`

If you wanted to test out serving your non-local development configuration you could copy the `serve` script and rename it `serve:local` and then edit the original `serve` script to look like this:

`vue-cli-service serve --mode development`

Which is really the actual default mode for `serve` out-of-the-box with CLI 3.  We've just explicitly set the mode.